# MySQL indexing on a non-primary-key column

Tags: mysql, database, indexing, primary-key

I am running some MySQL queries on a pretty large table (not on Facebook scale, but around a million rows), and I am finding them very slow. The reason, I suspect, is that I am querying on an `id` field, but that `id` has not been declared as primary key, and also no index has been declared.

I cannot set the `id` field to primary key, because it is not unique, although its cardinality is pretty close to 1. Under these circumstances, if I do a `alter table` to add an index on the `id` field, is it supposed to boost up the query speed, given that it is not a primary key?

And supposing it does, how long will it take for the index to develop fully so that the queries start executing quickly? I mean, the moment the prompt appears after executing the `alter table`, or is it that even though the prompt appears the index building will go on internally for quite some time? (I am asking before doing it because I am not sure whether declaring index on non-unique field corrupts the db or not)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any index will speed up queries that match on the corresponding column. There's no significant difference between the primary key and other indexes in this regard.

The index is created immediately when you execute the `ALTER TABLE` query. When the prompt returns, the index is there and will be used. There's no corruption while this is happening.

Comment: Cool. So in my case, since the cardinality will be pretty close to 1, the index will work as fine as on a primary key field, right? Will there be significant performance degradation? And, isn't the index creation an elaborate process? How can it be done instantly?

Comment: Whether it makes sense to use it as the primary key depends on your application. I said the index is created immediately, not instantaneously. It will take time if the table is large, but you don't get the prompt back until it's done -- it's not just starting a background task.